# Transfer Function of Controlled Capacitor Discharge

Tags: capacitor, inductor, control-system, pulse, high-current

I've been having some difficulties trying to design a closed loop, current pulse control system that controls a capacitor's discharge to an inductive load. The basic operating principle is that there is a capacitor, initially charged to some voltage V(0), that discharges across a mostly inductive load. Controlling the capacitor's discharge is a MOSFET that can modify the current flowing in the RLC loop. Shown below is a block diagram of the proposed system.

[image]

In the diagram, R(s) is the desired pulse shape, E(s) is the error signal, Vgs(s) is the voltage controlling the MOSFET gate, I(s) is the current in the RLC loop, and Vf(s) is the feedback voltage.

The MOSFET's gate-source voltage will be determined the by the transfer function:

$$
\frac{V_{GS}(s)}{E(s)}
$$

Which will act is the controller for this system. In order to determine this function and tune the controller, I first need to find the transfer function for:

$$
\frac{I(s)}{V_{GS}(s)}
$$

[image]

To determine the relationship between I(s) and Vgs(s), I am using some basic circuit analysis. Using KVL, we know that:

$$
-v_{r1}\left(t\right)-v_{r2}\left(t\right)-v_{r3}\left(t\right)-v_L\left(t\right)-v_c\left(t\right)-v_{mosfet}\left(t\right)=0
$$

Using the equations for voltage across each of the components, we have:

$$
-\left(R_1+R_2+R_3\right)i\left(t\right)-L\frac{di\left(t\right)}{dt}-\left[\frac{1}{C}\int i\left(t\right)dt+v_0\right]-Av_{GS}\left(t\right)=0
$$

Where A is some constant relating the MOSFET gate voltage to the drain-source voltage. This the relationship is assumed to be linear in order to simplify the calculations.

Upon converting into the frequency domain using a Laplace transform, I obtain the following expression:

$$
-\left(R_1+R_2+R_3\right)I\left(s\right)-LsI\left(s\right)-\left[\frac{1}{Cs}I\left(s\right)+\frac{V_0}{s}\right]-AV_{GS}\left(s\right)=0
$$

However, my issue arises from the fact that the the V0/s term (from the capacitors initial charge) doesn't allow me to isolate for I(s) and determine the transfer function:

$$
\frac{I(s)}{V_{GS}(s)}
$$

Ive done some reading and realized that a transfer function for this particular circuit may not be possible (maybe due to the fact that this is a relaxation oscillator?). Im trying to determine a way to tune the controller in Simulink, but I don't think I'll be able to do so unless I can find the transfer function above.

I'm wondering if there are any major flaws in my analysis that are preventing me from determining this transfer function. Let me know if you have an alternative approach to the design and modelling of this control system.

As a disclaimer, I am not an electrical engineer and I apologize if anything in the description above does not make sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A system's transfer function is defined as the ratio of its output to its input in the complex frequency domain **assuming** that the system has zero initial conditions. So, just drop the initial condition.